# Rails can't find record in db (but actual it exists)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

For example, I'm searching something in DB, `Model.find_by(slug: :name)`. And it's works ok in local env, but in test it gives me nil. (I triple checked it, and there is record in db).

I even added debug to view logs. And when I do `Model.where(slug: :name).count` it returns me 0. But record really exists with this slug name.

Where do I dig to fix this?

Comment: You checked to make sure the development and test databases the same?

Comment: *"I triple checked it, and there is record in db"* tripled checked your test database or your development database because they are generally separate databases by default and by design

Comment: No, there not. But I checked for requested record existing. For example, I added debugger: With "request.slug", it return me for 'administration' and I go in to test server DB and found record with slug 'administration'. So record exists.

Comment: Ofc, I'm checking test DB. Not my local!

Comment: are you using any testing framework?

Comment: Where are you running this statement, in a test or in console?

Comment: @J.D. test framework, like what? (I didn't noticed any)

Comment: @Iceman I mean test server, where it goes before deploy to production. As I said, I don't run this statement in console. I run it in model, and it run okey in local, but on test staging server (not test env) no record error appears

Comment: you wrote `but in test it gives me nil.` I just wonder - what test? How you test it? Rails has some testing frameworks, like default minitest (comes preinstalled with Rails), or RSpec etc. When using testing frameworks you define a database for it to use in your database.yml file (showing this file here might be useful)

Comment: Can you show us how you have written the test case...

Answer (score 0):

When running tests, Rails uses a different database. The common convention is projectname_development vs projectname_test (and finally projectname_production).

Commonly test systems also clear the test database before running a test. This is for two reasons:

- You don't want to mess with your development database through tests. Many developers let their tests run continuously during the development process.
- Every single test you write should work for itself, independent from data around it.

You have to set up your test data for every single test. You didn't mention what test system you use.

Have a look at [Fixtures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures) and [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl).

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not quite it. I know about this. What I'm telling that 'How it possible to `Model.find_by(slug: :name)` return nil, if record actually exists in DB, in model table.

Answer (score 0):

Data stored in the testing database is temporary and is removed after testing is over.
The development database is independent of the testing database.